Correlation vs Regression for a simple task
Hello everyone and thank you for taking the time with my issue! I want to apologize in advance if my question would've fit better on stack exchange, but I decided that the question is more related to mathematics than programming.
In the 9x9 matrix A, columns represent scores on different aspects of life (eg. Mental Health, Friends, Family). I want to check which column (aspect of real life) has the biggest "influence" on the rest:

Easiest way to code: Compute a vector X with the mean of each row: $$x_i = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{9}A_{i,j}}{9}$$ And just compute the correlation coefficient between each column vector of the matrix and X. I believe the correlation coefficient will be biased here since the variable we want to correlate with the mean is part of the "meaned" variables.
Much tougher to code efficiently (in my humble opinion): For each column vector of Matrix A, compute a vector X where: $$x_i =\frac{\sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^{9}A_{i,j}}{8} $$ Then compute the same correlation coefficient between the vectors. I am unsure whether the bias I mentioned in point 1 exists and therefore if figuring out how to code this in an efficient enough manner is worth the time investment.
While trying to solve this problem on my own, it crossed my mind that perhaps some kind of MLR would be a better solution for my problem, so therefore I decided to seek advice from some better mathematicians.

Thank you for reading my post! I am a new poster here and I would definitely appreciate feedback on the format of my question!
